# Creating walls for a racing game?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, racing

I have the following kind of race track:

[image]

As you can see some walls are talls but some aren't...

**Question:**

How can one create invisible walls so that cars stays in track?

More exactly, how to model walls for complex shapes in a relatively easy way?

Comment: why you can not place empty object with collider..?

Comment: What is the effect of your game crashing into them? You can't just go there, you do some collision/ spinning, you can fall offtrack and need to reset your car, you loose speed, etc?

Comment: @ShoulO Care to elaborate ?

Comment: @Zibelas The car can't fall off into scenery, it must stay in the track, and yes, loose some speed.

Comment: @aybe You are using Unity, right? so why not to create empty objects (objects which are invisible with only transform component), add box colider , and you have yourself invisible walls...

Comment: @ShoulO Yes, the actual problem is not with that, rather, how can I relatively easily create such shape ? If the race track was rectangle shaped, it'd take 1 minute to create walls using box colliders. But it isn't, it's made of arbitrariliy curved turns, steeps etc, like in real world, hence my idea of ProBuilder... but I just tried it, it doesn't seem to be the right tool at all unless I am mistaken.

Comment: If you have modelled the track yourself, it wouldn't be so hard to add these collision meshes into the model as child objects. If you have just imported this from some other source and cannot change it externally, then perhaps you can do as ShoulO suggests. Just make several 'pieces' that you can reuse (objects with just collider and no mesh etc)  and match it up with the model as best you can in Unity Editor

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question as apparently I didn't make it clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up creating my own editor tool/window combo:

[image]

The general idea is the following:

Click a quad vertex, add a wall point, upper point is just `Vector3.up`.

And allow to remove any point as well.

Along necessary data/logic, etc.

Though manually paint, any vertex can form a collider thus I'll get vertex perfect colliders.

**EDIT:**

I now leverage the following:

- store data directly in game objects
- a global editor tool + a custom window in scene view
- scriptable singleton for tool data

[image]